# How do I nest base templates in Hugo?

Tags: hugo, go-templates

I'm trying to do the following in Hugo:

`layouts/_default/baseof.html`:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <span>main baseof.html</span>
        {{ block "body" . }} 
        
        {{ end }}
    </body>
</html>
```

`layouts/posts/baseof.html`:

```html
{{ define "body" }}
    <span>posts baseof.html</span>
    {{ block "main" . }}

    {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

`layouts/posts/single.html`:

```html
{{ define "main" }}
    <h1>{{ .Title }}</h1>
            
    {{ .Content }}
{{ end }}
```

I'm expecting the following output:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <span>main baseof.html</span>
        <span>posts baseof.html</span>
        <h1>Post Title</h1>
            
        <p>Post Content</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it's not working. I just get an empty page.

If I replace `layouts/posts/baseof.html` with plain HTML (no `define` blocks), it works, but then it doesn't inherit the common stuff from `layouts/_default/baseof.html`.

Comment: From the "Base template lookup order" section in [Base templates and blocks](https://gohugo.io/templates/base/). The `baseof.html` pages don't accumulate in that way. Instead, hugo chooses just *one* `baseof.html`. Your original `layouts/posts/baseof.html` doesn't have a <html> element so there's nowhere for a "body" or "main" block to be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

For nesting I would use this structure:

`layouts/_default/baseof.html:`

```
<html>
    <body>
        <span>main baseof.html</span>
        {{ block "body" . }} 
        
        {{ end }}
    </body>
</html>
```

`layouts/posts/single.html:`

```
{{ define "body" }}
    {{ partial "mypostpartial.html" . }}
    <h1>{{ .Title }}</h1>
            
    {{ .Content }}
{{ end }}
```

`layouts/partials/mypostpartial.html:`

```
<span>posts partial content</span>
```

I do not think that `Sections` have their own baseof templates.